# Gstreamer element properties that depend on another property

Tags: gstreamer

I am writing a gstreamer element, and I want to add a property that selects the algorithm that the element will use to perform its function.

```
gst-launch ... ! myelement algo=1 ! ...
```

Now, suppose I have two alghoritms, and I need to be able to specify different parameters for each algorithm, and naturally I would want that the user is able to set these parameters through properties.

For example, algorithm 1 would use a property named x:

```
gst-launch ... ! myelement algo=1 x=10 ! ...
```

But algorithm 2 would use a property named y (and it doesn't need x):

```
gst-launch ... ! myelement algo=2 y=20 ! ...
```

Essentially, some properties will have meaning only depending on the value of another property.

What is the standard way of handling this? Should I add properties 'x' and 'y' and document that 'x' only works when algo=1 and 'y' only works when algo=2?

Or, should I forget about the 'algo' property and make two different elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To look for a standard way to handle things in gstreamer is always a good idea to check what other elements do. A great example for this case could be the element 'multifilesink' which has several ways to handle file segmentation; looking at the properties (running gst-inspect multifilesink on the cmdline) you can see that the property "max-file-size" only makes sense if the "next-file" property is set to 4, thus its description is used to specify it :

" max-file-size       : Maximum file size before starting a new file in max-size mode "